# Service is using other service's static files

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two services, `beta` and `default` (they are both Flask apps). In addition, a custom domain (`example.com`) is setup. The problem is that `beta.example.com` is using `default`'s static files, while `default` works properly. Does anyone know how I could fix this? Would I need to create a backend for static files?

Here is `beta`'s `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37

service: beta

handlers:
- url: /static/
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

And here is `default`'s:

```
runtime: python37

service: default

handlers:
- url: /static/
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

And my `dispatch.yaml`:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "example.com/"
    service: default
  - url: "beta.example.com/"
    service: beta
```

Comment: What's the directory structure of your application (from where you deploy your services) and the positions of the 2 `.yaml` files in it?

Comment: Try adding a `*` at the end of each `url` statements in your `dispatch.yaml` file

Comment: @DanCornilescu [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/xTDZJ5kE) is my directory structure. I had problems with comment formatting so I used pastebin.

Comment: dir structure is ok. Never mind, it's not that. Check that `*` wildcard - I suspect it may be routing just the top level url specified, but nothing just starting with that url pattern.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I just readded the records, somehow it works now. I am going to add them again to make sure this is reproducible.

Comment: Seems to be reproducible. I am going to close this now. Odd, as I didn't change anything.

Comment: Could be a caching issue.

Comment: Possibly. I am using cloudflare.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Happened again. I did not do anything. I have just set cloudflare into development mode, but it didn't change anything. I also tried in incognito mode so there's no cache.

Comment: I also tried the wildcard in dispatch.yaml, unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: Aaaand, beta is back. I am going to leave this open for a few more hours.

Comment: You shouldn't delete the question, it can be useful to others. Just add an answer explaining how it was resolved.

Comment: Ok. Though I don't exactly know how I fixed it.